# Return table data of foreign key with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, orm, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

I have the following data returned from Sequelize, but I want another value from the Key-table instead of ID_Key (e.g.: KeyName, that is available in Key-table).

```
[
{"ID_Translation":1,"ID_Language":1,"ID_Key":2,"TargetText":"TextTranslation2"},
{"ID_Translation":2,"ID_Language":1,"ID_Key":1,"TargetText":"TextTranslation1"},
{"ID_Translation":3,"ID_Language":1,"ID_Key":3,"TargetText":"TextTranslation3"}
]
```

My Query:

```
Translation.findAll({
  where: {
    ID_Language: 1,
  }
}).then(Translations => {
  console.log("All Translations:", JSON.stringify(Translations));
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you associate `translations` with `Key-table` ? you can `include` associated models using `include` property inside queries. for example :
let suppose that you have a model named `Key` associated with your `Translations` model, and you have a 1-N association between these models like that:

`Key.hasMany(Translation, {foreignKey: 'ID_Key'});`

`Translation.belongsTo(Key, {foreignKey: 'ID_Translation'});`

you can do:

```
Translation.findAll({
  where: {
   ID_Language: 1,
  },
  include: [
   Key
  ],
})
```

when you fetch all `Translation`, you will have a `Key` property inside translation object as a result of association. that is `eager loading`.

see more on docs: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-usage.html#eager-loading

Comment: can you please tell me how to add this to mongo and provide above method sample output.